# Rest Api field Shipvia incorrect value

Tags: acumatica

When we create soshipment with API, the field SHIPVIA is ok,
But when we add some solines, the fielshipvia is ko.

In this example, we have "ROUTE" in the order, but we put "TRAIN" in the shipment.
It's a pity that the webservice is not working properly

> {"CustomerID": {"value": "HOTELLAC"}, "Hold": {"value": true},
> "ShipmentDate": {"value": "2023-07-04T00:00:00+00:00"}, "Type":
> {"value": "I"},"Operation": {"value": "I"},"WarehouseID": {"value":
> "PARIS"}, "Details": [{"OrderNbr": {"value": "000908"}, "OrderType":
> {"value": "SO"},"OrderLineNbr": {"value": 1},"ShippedQty": {"value":
> 1}}], "ShipVia": {"value": "TRAIN"}}

I use this URL https://XXXXXXXX/entity/FFY/20.200.001/Shipment?$expand=Details

Comment: Please update your question with a full request, including the endpoint name and version you use.

Comment: You seem to be using a custom endpoint. The field Ship via is not in the default entity shipment detail. Could you add screen shots of the shipment and shipment detail entity for your custom endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we add an order to a shipment, the shipment's ShipVia is defaulted from the order. To avoid this, we need to override SetShipmentFieldsFromOrder function on SOShipmentEntryGraph.
I tested this solution on 23R1.

```
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.SO;

namespace PX.Objects
{
   public class SOShipmentEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
   {
    public delegate bool SetShipmentFieldsFromOrderDelegate(SOOrder order, SOShipment shipment,
        int? siteID, DateTenter code hereime? shipDate, string operation, SOOrderTypeOperation orderOperation,
        bool newlyCreated);

    [PXOverride]
    public virtual bool SetShipmentFieldsFromOrder(SOOrder order, SOShipment shipment,
        int? siteID, DateTime? shipDate, string operation, SOOrderTypeOperation orderOperation,
        bool newlyCreated, SetShipmentFieldsFromOrderDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        // Save the ShipVia, we need to restore it after the shipment is created.
        var oldShipVia = order.ShipVia;
        if (newlyCreated)
        {
            order.ShipVia = shipment.ShipVia;
        }

        var result = baseMethod(order, shipment, siteID, shipDate, operation, orderOperation, newlyCreated);

        if (newlyCreated)
        {
            // Restore ShipVia on the order, without this Shipment's ShipVia will overwrite it.
            order.ShipVia = oldShipVia;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you need the key when you are trying to update a record. He is trying to create a new Shipment so no key required in this scenario.

Comment: @samol518 I missed the creating shipment part, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @ZoltanFebert ! I just update some argument in SetShipmentFieldsFromOrderDelegate for my version 2022R2 :) It's so good now